# How to permanently disable payment button after successful payment in Android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, android-studio

I have a android studio project that is an E-Book. There is a Razorpay payment gateway in this project. I want to disable payment button permanently after successful payment. That means if a user use back press or reopen the app this payment button do not show after one successful payment. Please help me and thank you for reading...

This is my code

```
public class DetailsActivity extends BaseActivity implements PaymentResultListener  {
```

ImageView RazerPayButn;
NestedScrollView ScroolBtn;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    ScroolBtn = findViewById(R.id.scrollviewid);
    RazerPayButn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.razorpay);
```

}

```
public void startPayment() {
@Override
public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
    Log.d("ONSUCCESS", "onPaymentSuccess: " + s);

}



@Override
public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
    Log.d("ONERROR", "onPaymentError: "+s);

}



public void onClick(View v){
    startPayment();
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    RazerPayButn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ScroolBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The payment button reappears when the app is reopened or when the back button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You could use [data store](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) or [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to save data permanently in a local database. Consider if the user clears the application storage your data will be lost. Another approach could be sending data to the server side and getting it from the server.